# Trouble with Django, request and logging in?

Tags: python, django, request

Hey All-
  I'm completely new to Django/python and am going through a tutorial for a class, located [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1015145/csci-4380/tutorial/index.html). I've got most of this working, but I'm having trouble. I can register a user, but seemingly cannot login. For the relevant part of the tutorial, search for the line `We’ll need one more form, a login form:` which explains how to implement the login form. I did this and the form works and I can "login" and I do get a session cookie on the client.

The problem is, if you scroll down a little more, you'll see `We should add a welcome message and login/logout links to our templates:` which explains how to show a user a welcome message if they're logged in, or a login link if they're not. Problem is, after logging in, I still get a login link!

Now, the tutorial explains this. It says I need to do two things: 1) Put the following code in my settings.py file

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = [
    "django.core.context_processors.request"
]
```

2) Create a file called middleware.py which will set the request.user value. I've done this and restarted my server but I still have my same problem. (The code is in the tutorial, but I'll paste here too for simplicity):

```
from users.models import User
class UserMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        user_id = request.session.get("user_id")
        if user_id is not None:
            request.user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        else:
            request.user = None
```

I tried changing the syntax on that first part a bit to the below:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

which better matched the other lines in settings.py, but this didn't help either.

I know this is a huge wall of text, but can someone point me in the right direction? This itself is not an assignment, just a tutorial for a later assignment, so help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added your new middleware class to the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` list in settings.py?

Comment: I am told that if the view uses RequestContext that this isn't necessary. Still, how can I go about doing this to be safe?

Comment: I went ahead and did this and it worked. It wasn't mentioned in the tutorial, don't know why, but it is working now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In real life, you'd use django.contrub.auth for login/authentication.

It looks you don't set request.session["user_id"] to user.pk. As I see, this is done in the login view in the tutorial. Is your login view exactly the same as in tutorial? Do you have method="post" in your login form?

Comment: My login view is identical to the one in the tutorial. Here is my users/views.py file: http://python.pastebin.com/qF8VTAVr  and the HTML for the login form is method POST.